# Isuue with VF Rendering

Tags: apex, visualforce

**My vf page :**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="relevant">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageBlock id="block">

            <apex:pageblockSection >
                <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                    <apex:commandButton Value="Select Resolution" action="{!SelectResolution}" title="Selected Resolution will be copied in current Case resolution field" />
                    <apex:commandButton id="btn1" Value="Clear" action="{!Back}" reRender="form" title="" disabled="false" />
                </apex:outputpanel>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
            <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg" />
            <apex:outputPanel id="show1">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Resolution In Detail" >
                <apex:outputText >{!Des}</apex:outputText>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:outputPanel id="op" styleClass="displayblock">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Possible Resolution's" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable rows="6" value="{!performcallout}" var="wrap" width="100%">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                        <input type="radio" name="<strong>selectRadio</strong>" id="radio">
                        <br/>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getSelected}" rerender="show1,showmsg">
                            <apex:param name="wrapid" value="{!wrap.name}" />
                        </apex:actionSupport>
                        </input>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Case Id">
                        <apex:commandLink value="{!wrap.Name}" /> </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Case Resolution">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!wrap.Email}" /> </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Confidence Score">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!wrap.AccNumber}" /> </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller :**

```
public with sharing class relevant {

    public List < consolewrap > ConsoleWrapperList {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String wrapid {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String Des {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public case currentRecord {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string currentCaseId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Boolean Flag {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Map < String, String > pairingmap = new Map < String, String > ();
    public relevant(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        currentCaseId = '5002800000X1ilT';
        currentRecord = [SELECT Id, Description FROM Case WHERE Id =: currentCaseId];

    }
    public List < consolewrap > getperformcallout() {
        ConsoleWrapperList = new List < consolewrap > ();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        req.setEndpoint('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parthiban019/samplejson/master/student.json');
        //req.setEndpoint(endoint);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        system.debug('req ' + req);
        res = http.send(req);
        system.debug('res' + res);
        system.debug('resbody' + res.getbody());
        if (res.getstatusCode() == 200 && res.getbody() != null) {
         ConsoleWrapperList = (List < consolewrap > ) json.deserialize(res.getbody(), List < consolewrap > .class);
        }

        return consolewrapperlist;

    }
    public void getSelected() {
        System.debug('Entered Case selection block');
         wrapid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('wrapid');
        system.debug('weaa' + wrapid);


        for (consolewrap cl: consolewrapperlist) {
            pairingmap.put(cl.name, cl.email);
            system.debug('@@@pairingmap' + pairingmap);
        }

        currentRecord.Description = pairingmap.get(wrapid);
        Des = pairingmap.get(wrapid);
        system.debug('##des' + Des);
      system.debug('weaa' + wrapid);

    }
    public PageReference SelectResolution() {
     system.debug(''+wrapid);
        //  wrapid= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('wrapid');
        if (wrapid != null) {

            //currentCaseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

            Update currentRecord;

        } else {

            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING, 'You have not selected any resolution'));
            return null;

        }
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + currentCaseId);

        return pageRef;
    }
    public string View() {
    system.debug('Inside View');
    system.debug('hloooo'+wrapid );

        if (wrapid!=null) {

            Flag = true;

        }
        else{
         ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING, 'You have not selected any resolution'));
        }
      //  wrapid = null;
        system.debug('viewwwww'+wrapid);
        return null;
    }
    public String Back() {
        wrapid = null;
        return wrapid ;

    }
}
```

I want that "Resolution In Detail" should be visible only if any radio button is selected and should disappear on clicking Clear. Please help me to correct my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added one Boolean properties **radioBtnStatus** to hold value for button to render or not based on your requirement .

Small change with **`<apex:actionSupport>`**  and **`<apex:commandButton rendered="{! radioBtnStatus}">`** property added.

**VisualForce :**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="relevant">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageBlock id="block">            
            <apex:pageblockSection >
                <apex:outputPanel id="btn">
                    <apex:commandButton Value="Select Resolution" action="{!SelectResolution}" title="Selected Resolution will be copied in current Case resolution field" rendered="{! radioBtnStatus}" />
                    <apex:commandButton id="btn1" Value="Clear" action="{!Back}" reRender="form"  />
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
            <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg" />
            <apex:outputPanel id="show1" >
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Resolution In Detail" rendered="{! radioBtnStatus}" >
                    <apex:outputText >{!Des}</apex:outputText>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:outputPanel id="op" styleClass="displayblock">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Possible Resolution's" columns="1">
                    <apex:pageBlockTable rows="6" value="{!performcallout}" var="wrap" width="100%">
                        <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                            <input type="radio" name="<strong>selectRadio</strong>" id="radio"/>                       
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getSelected}" reRender="showmsg,show1,btn" >
                                <apex:param name="wrapid" value="{!wrap.name}" />
                            </apex:actionSupport>                       
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Case Id">
                            <apex:commandLink value="{!wrap.Name}" /> </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Case Resolution">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!wrap.Email}" /> </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Confidence Score">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!wrap.AccNumber}" /> </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller :**

```
public with sharing class relevant{
    public Boolean radioBtnStatus{get;set;}
    public List < consolewrap > ConsoleWrapperList { get;set;}
    public String wrapid {get;set;}
    public String Des {get;set;}
    public case currentRecord {get;set;}
    public string currentCaseId {get;set;}
    public Boolean Flag {get;set;}

    public Map < String, String > pairingmap = new Map < String, String > ();
    public relevant(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        currentCaseId = '5002800000X1ilT';
        currentRecord = [SELECT Id, Description FROM Case WHERE Id =: currentCaseId];        
    }
    public List < consolewrap > getperformcallout() {
        ConsoleWrapperList = new List < consolewrap > ();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        req.setEndpoint('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parthiban019/samplejson/master/student.json');
        //req.setEndpoint('http://gitrepoz.cloudapp.net/NlpSearch/');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        system.debug('req ' + req);
        res = http.send(req);
        system.debug('res' + res);
        system.debug('resbody' + res.getbody());
        if (res.getstatusCode() == 200 && res.getbody() != null) {
            ConsoleWrapperList = (List < consolewrap > ) json.deserialize(res.getbody(), List < consolewrap > .class);
        }        
        return consolewrapperlist;        
    }
    public void getSelected() {
        radioBtnStatus=true;
        System.debug('Entered Case selection block');
        wrapid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('wrapid');
        system.debug('weaa' + wrapid);

        for (consolewrap cl: consolewrapperlist) {
            pairingmap.put(cl.name, cl.email);
            system.debug('@@@pairingmap' + pairingmap);
        }        
        currentRecord.Description = pairingmap.get(wrapid);
        Des = pairingmap.get(wrapid);
        system.debug('##des' + Des);
        system.debug('weaa' + wrapid);        
    }
    public PageReference SelectResolution() {
        system.debug(''+wrapid);
        //  wrapid= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('wrapid');
        if (wrapid != null) {            
            //currentCaseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');            
            Update currentRecord;            
        } else {            
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING, 'You have not selected any resolution'));
            return null;            
        }
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + currentCaseId);        
        return pageRef;
    }
    public string View() {
        system.debug('Inside View');
        system.debug('hloooo'+wrapid );        
        if (wrapid!=null) {            
            Flag = true;            
        }
        else{
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING, 'You have not selected any resolution'));
        }
        //  wrapid = null;
        system.debug('viewwwww'+wrapid);
        return null;
    }
    public String Back() {
        radioBtnStatus=false;
        wrapid = null;
        return wrapid ;

    }
    public class consolewrap {
        public String Name{get;set;}
        public String AccNumber{get;set;}
        public String Source{get;set;}
        public String Site{get;set;}
        public String Email{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `rendered` attribute appear in the `id="show1"` output panel?

Comment: @mahmood  Sorry forgot add rendered="{! radioBtnStatus}" to outputpanel show1

Comment: @Nitesh : Thanks a lot! it worked :) but rendered needs to be added at pageblock section rather than output pannel

Comment: @Nikki Welcome, Yes, i did but your radio button was getting cleared because of the entire page block was refreshing .

Comment: @Nikki answer posted by #mahmood also a good solution if your page already has Jquery library included .

Answer (score 1):

Besides the solution already presented with `rendered` attribute, a boolean flag at the controller side, and `rerender` the specific component upon some desired event, you could use basic Javascript or jQuery to the achieve the same impact.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Resolution In Detail" id="resolution" >
    <apex:outputText >{!Des}</apex:outputText>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

> **jQuery**

```
// on click of radio btn, show resolution
j$( "#radio" ).click(function() {
  j$('#resolution').show();
});
// on click of Clear btn, hide resolution
j$( "#btn1" ).click(function() {
  j$('#resolution').hide();
});
```

P.S. Refer to the article [using jQuery in a VF page](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-jquery-in-a-visualforce-page), if you are unsure about using jQuery.

Comment: Thanx Mahmood :)